# Saving objects in localStorage which has a method

Tags: javascript, object, local-storage

The problem is that I am saving projects, which are made with project factory function. The projects also have addToDo method and I am saving this projects into myProjects array.

I am struggling with, that when my projects are saved or retrieved to/from localStorage,  they loose functionality (addToDo method). As after page refresh I can't add todos to the projects anymore. So I guess that method of project factory isn't saved to localStorage. Thanks.

```
let newProject;
let myProjects = localStorage.getItem("projects")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("projects"))
  : [
    
  ];

const saveToLocalStorage = () => {
  localStorage.setItem("projects", JSON.stringify(myProjects));
};

// Project factory, which takes in title and makes toDo array, to which the toDos will be added...
const newProjectFactory = (id, title) => {
  const toDos = [];

  const add_toDo = (toDo) => {
    toDos.push(toDo);
  };

  return { id, title, toDos, add_toDo };
};

const newProjectEvent = (event) => {
  // DOM elements of form ...
  event.preventDefault();
  const newProjectTitle = document.getElementById("newProjectName").value;

  let ID;
  if (myProjects.length > 0) {
    ID = myProjects[myProjects.length - 1].id + 1;
  } else {
    ID = 0;
  }

  newProject = newProjectFactory(ID, newProjectTitle);

  myProjects.push(newProject);
  
};
```

Comment: You can only save strings in local storage, and `JSON.stringify()` ignores function values of object properties.

Comment: Add a constructor to your object that takes the data and sets its properties with that data. Use that constructor to instantiate objects with data from localStorage.

Comment: Storing Functions for later use will allow me to just override that space and update the function with malicious intent.  Luckily, Browsers will cache the js file itself so there arent network requests later on, so storing it in a js file should be fine.  Source:  Ive jacked some systems through people attempting to eval function strings.  payloads will be smaller if you do persist the data and pass it into a javascript constructor.

Comment: So basically I should retrieve data from localStorage and put it into projectFactory, and todo items in toDoFactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pattern like this might be useful. You can keep them in an single object or create two functions such as `newProjectFactory` and `newProjectFromJSON`.

```
const Project = {
  factory: (id, title) => {
    return Project.from({ id, title });
  },
  from: (state) => {
    const { toDos = [], id, title } = state || {};

    const add_toDo = (toDo) => {
      toDos.push(toDo);
    };

    return { id, title, toDos, add_toDo };
  }
};

const project = Project.factory(1, 'title');
project.add_toDo('taco');

const json = JSON.stringify(project);
const deserialized = Project.from(JSON.parse(json));
console.log(deserialized);
```

The `factory` method is exactly what you have now, it simply creates a new project given your factory inputs. The `from` method is a little closer to the metal where it allows you inject specific state properties. The `factory` simply creates a more ergonomic api for creating projects while the `from` is used to marshal data.

Another thing you might want to consider is adding a `toJSON` method on the factory object. This will allow you to add private fields to json as well that may not be serialized while using the normal revealing pattern. A good use case is probably the `toDos` array. You probably don't want that public but want it in json.

```
const newProjectfactory = () => {
  const toDos = [];
  
  const toJSON = () => {
    return { toDos };
  };
  
  const addTodo = (todo) => {
    toDos.push(todo);
  };
  
  return {
    addTodo,
    toJSON
  };
}

const project = newProjectfactory();
console.log(JSON.stringify(project));
```