# JavaScript - Issues recovering a map in an object after being saved in localStorage

Tags: javascript

I've been dealing with this for some time. I've a list of sections in which the user checks some checkboxes and that is sent to the server via AJAX. However, since the user can return to previous sections, I'm using some objects of mine to store some things the user has done (if he/she already finished working in that section, which checkboxes checked, etc). I'm doing this to not overload the database and only send new requests to store information if the user effectively changes a previous checkbox, not if he just starts clicking "Save" randomly. I'm using objects to see the sections of the page, and storing the previous state of the checkboxes in a Map. Here's my "supervisor":

```
function Supervisor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.verif = null; 
    this.selections = new Map();
    var children = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_checkboxes_div_" + id).children().length;
    for (var i = 0; i < children; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            var checkbox = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_checkboxes_div_" + id).children()[i];
            var idCheck = checkbox.id.split("_")[2];
            this.selections.set(idCheck, false);
        }
    }
    console.log("Length " + this.selections.size);
    this.change = false;
}
```

The console.log gives me the expected output, so I assume my Map is created and initialized correctly. Since the session of the user can expire before he finishes his work, or he can close his browser by accident, I'm storing this object using local storage, so I can change the page accordingly to what he has done should anything happen. Here are my functions:

```
function setObj(id, supervisor) {
    localStorage.setItem(id, JSON.stringify(supervisor));
}

function getObj(key) {
    var supervisor = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    return supervisor;
}
```

So, I'm trying to add to the record whenever an user clicks in a checkbox. And this is where the problem happens. Here's the function:

```
function checkboxClicked(idCbx) {
    var idSection = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_hdnActualField").val();
    var supervisor = getObj(idSection);
    console.log(typeof (supervisor)); //Returns object, everythings fine
    console.log(typeof (supervisor.change)); //Returns boolean
    supervisor.change = true;
    var idCheck = idCbx.split("_")[2]; //I just want a part of the name
    console.log(typeof(supervisor.selections)); //Prints object
    console.log("Length " + supervisor.selections.size); //Undefined!
    supervisor.selections.set(idCheck, true); //Error! Note: The true is just for testing purposes
    setObj(idSection, supervisor);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: localstorage and json are not meant to store object instances like `Map`

Comment: @DanielA.White so I've been playing myself, thanks dude. If you wish, could you post it as an answer so my dumb ass will serve as an example for another lost dude in the future?

Comment: Please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141609/saving-objects-in-localstorage-which-has-a-method/64142092). Its a slightly different case but you should be able to use those concepts to marshal data in and out of localstorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at this example, I removed the jquery id discovery for clarity. You'll need to adapt this to meet your needs but it should get you mostly there.

```
const mapToJSON = (map) => [...map];

const mapFromJSON = (json) => new Map(json);

function Supervisor(id) {
  this.id = id;
  this.verif = null;
  this.selections = new Map();
  this.change = false;
  
  this.selections.set('blah', 'hello');
}

Supervisor.from = function (data) {
  const id = data.id;
  const supervisor = new Supervisor(id);
  
  supervisor.verif = data.verif;
  supervisor.selections = new Map(data.selections);
  
  return supervisor;
};

Supervisor.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  return {
    id: this.id,
    verif: this.verif,
    selections: mapToJSON(this.selections)
  }
}

const expected = new Supervisor(1);
console.log(expected);

const json = JSON.stringify(expected);
const actual = Supervisor.from(JSON.parse(json));
console.log(actual);
```

If you cant use the spread operation in 'mapToJSON' you could loop and push.

```
const mapToJSON = (map) => {
  const result = [];

  for (let entry of map.entries()) {
    result.push(entry);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Really the only thing id change is have the constructor do less, just accept values, assign with minimal fiddling, and have a factory query the dom and populate the constructor with values. Maybe something like `fromDOM()` or something. This will make `Supervisor` more flexible and easier to test.

```
function Supervisor(options) {
  this.id = options.id;
  this.verif = null;
  this.selections = options.selections || new Map();
  this.change = false;
}

Supervisor.fromDOM = function(id) {
  const selections = new Map();
  const children = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_checkboxes_div_" + id).children();
    
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      var checkbox = children[i];
      var idCheck = checkbox.id.split("_")[2];
      selections.set(idCheck, false);
    }
  }
  
  return new Supervisor({ id: id, selections: selections });
};

console.log(Supervisor.fromDOM(2));
```

You can keep going and have another method that tries to parse a `Supervisor` from `localStorage`and default to the dom based factory if the localStorage one returns null.